# How to start X server in Debian Wheezy mips running on qemu?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, mips

I created a debian mips virtual machine by downloading qcow2 images from [here](https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/mips/). I then started the virtual machine by

```
qemu-system-mips \
-m 256 \
-M malta \
-kernel vmlinux-3.2.0-4-4kc-malta \
-hda debian_wheezy_mips_standard.qcow2 \
-append "root=/dev/sda1 console=tty0" \
-net user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22 \
-net nic
```

I can ssh into the machine and can create a vnc server by appending `-vnc :1`. But I cannot start X by typing startx or any means. I have installed all necessary packages using `apt-get install xfonts-base xfonts-cyrillic xserver-xorg-video-vesa lightdm`

I created a new configuration by using `X -configure` But it says

```
vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver

Backtrace:
0: X (xorg_backtrace+0x70) [0x5a3980]

Segmentation fault at address (nil)

Fatal server error:
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
```

Running `startx` gives

`Fatal server error: no screens found`

This is the full /var/log/Xorg.0.log from the guest debian machine:

```
X.Org X Server 1.12.4
Release Date: 2012-08-27
[   437.907] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   437.909] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-4-octeon mips Debian
[   437.910] Current Operating System: Linux debian-mips 3.2.0-4-4kc-malta #1 Debian 3.2.51-1 mips
[   437.911] Kernel command line: root=/dev/sda1 console=tty0
[   437.916] Build Date: 09 February 2015  10:24:38AM
[   437.916] xorg-server 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u6 (Julien Cristau <jcristau@debian.org>)
[   437.916] Current version of pixman: 0.26.0
[   437.917]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   437.917] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   437.925] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat May 11 10:25:13 2019
[   437.952] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   437.971] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   437.972] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   437.972] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   437.973] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   437.983] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[   437.985] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   437.985] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   437.986] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[   437.987]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   437.987] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
        built-ins
[   437.987] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   437.987] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   437.987] (II) Loader magic: 0x5ee010
[   437.987] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   437.987]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   437.987]    X.Org Video Driver: 12.1
[   437.988]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[   437.988]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[   437.995] (--) PCI:*(0:0:18:0) 1013:00b8:1af4:1100 rev 0, Mem @ 0x10000000/33554432, 0x12050000/4096, BIOS @ 0x????????/65536
[   437.996] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[   438.006] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[   438.011] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   438.011]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   438.012]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   438.012]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   438.013] (II) Loading extension SELinux
[   438.013] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   438.013] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   438.013] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[   438.013] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[   438.014] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[   438.014] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   438.014] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[   438.014] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[   438.017] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[   438.019] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   438.019]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   438.019]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   438.019]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   438.019] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   438.019] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   438.020] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   438.022] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   438.022]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   438.022]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   438.022] (==) AIGLX enabled
[   438.023] (II) Loading extension GLX
[   438.023] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[   438.024] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[   438.025] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   438.025]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.13.0
[   438.025]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   438.025]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   438.025] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[   438.025] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[   438.027] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[   438.028] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   438.028]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   438.028]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   438.029] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[   438.029] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   438.030] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[   438.031] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   438.032]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.2.0
[   438.032]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[   438.032] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[   438.032] (==) Matched cirrus as autoconfigured driver 0
[   438.032] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   438.033] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   438.033] (II) LoadModule: "cirrus"
[   438.034] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/cirrus_drv.so
[   438.035] (II) Module cirrus: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   438.035]    compiled for 1.12.1.902, module version = 1.4.0
[   438.035]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   438.035]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[   438.035] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   438.036] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   438.037] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   438.037]    compiled for 1.12.1, module version = 0.4.2
[   438.037]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[   438.037] (II) CIRRUS: driver for Cirrus chipsets: CLGD5430, CLGD5434-4, CLGD5434-8,
        CLGD5436, CLGD5446, CLGD5480, CL-GD5462, CL-GD5464, CL-GD5464BD,
        CL-GD5465, CL-GD7548, CL-GD7555, CL-GD7556
[   438.038] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   438.040] (--) using VT number 7

[   438.060] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for cirrus
[   438.061] (--) Assigning device section with no busID to primary device
[   438.061] (--) Chipset CLGD5446 found
[   438.062] (EE) cirrus: The PCI device 0xb8 at 00@00:18:0 has a kernel module claiming it.
[   438.062] (EE) cirrus: This driver cannot operate until it has been unloaded.
[   438.062] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   438.062] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   438.062] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   438.063] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   438.065] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   438.065]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 0.0.2
[   438.065]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.1
[   438.066] (EE) No devices detected.
[   438.066]
Fatal server error:
[   438.066] no screens found
[   438.066]
```

I am using a nixos 19.03 machine as the host and compiled qemu from git.